# Android Studio won't run simple app on one machine

Tags: java, android

I have a student doing a very basic introduction to mobile apps in Android Studio. Because of lockdown, all the students are running from home, with their own installations of AS. I have one student in particular who is having a problem just getting a simple app to run. His code is correct - it's the same as all the other students are using without a problem, but when he tries to start the program he gets the following errors appearing in the error pane.

We've reinstalled Android Studio, and still with the same error. If I run it on my PC, the app executes without a problem (using API 24), so it's got to be something in his configuration, but I'm unable to find the issue. What might be going wrong here? I realise it's a big dump of error code!

Error message:

```
com.android.tools.r8.a: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.r.a(:291)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.r.a(:98)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.r.b(:188)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(:63)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:322)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:66)
                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(:46)
                at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:92)
                at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
                at com.android.tools.r8.utils.W.a(:30)
                at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
                at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:116)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.process(DexingTransform.kt:296)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.processNonIncrementally(DexingTransform.kt:243)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.doTransform(DexingTransform.kt:153)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.access$doTransform(DexingTransform.kt:69)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform$transform$1.invoke(DexingTransform.kt:104)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform$transform$1.invoke(DexingTransform.kt:69)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BlocksUtilsKt.recordArtifactTransformSpan(BlocksUtils.kt:33)
                at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.transform(DexingTransform.kt:100)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformer.transform(DefaultTransformer.java:189)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:332)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
                at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
                at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
                at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
                at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$2.lambda$call$2(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:200)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:269)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.access$300(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:79)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$2.call(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:178)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$2.call(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:175)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.lambda$doTransform$0(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:175)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
                at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
                at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:181)
                at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:172)
                at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:196)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:56)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4718)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3445)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2194)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2153)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2043)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3851)
                at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4713)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:55)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.doTransform(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:175)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.access$000(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:79)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:141)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$1.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:58)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ChainedTransformationNode$1.lambda$transform$0(TransformationNode.java:226)
                at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.flatMap(Try.java:157)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ChainedTransformationNode$1.transform(TransformationNode.java:225)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:267)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:247)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
                at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
                at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ChainedTransformationNode.execute(TransformationNode.java:222)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.WorkNodeExecutor.execute(WorkNodeExecutor.java:27)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
                at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
                at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
                at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
                Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.r8.a: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
                                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
                                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:513)
                                at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:86)
                                at com.android.tools.r8.utils.U0.a(:14)
                                at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.b(:101)
                                ... 120 more
                Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: com.android.tools.r8.a: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)]
```

Comment: the device that your student uses is less than android O the minimum API level in your app-level Gradle file is 26  so it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I suspected that, but it's working fine with mine at API 24. 
I'll get him to create a new emulator and run it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

You must create emulator with api 26 level.

Comment: Ah...found the issue, thanks to you folks!
I took him into the Gradle build version and modified in code to run at Min 27 and Target 30, and it worked. It looks like he'd originally set the Min at 15. 
Thanks all fo your suggestions!